# Is the annotation @EnableMongoRepositories required while creating rest endpoints using Spring data rest @RepositoryRestResource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I was trying out the spring boot guide to create a spring data rest endpoint using the `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation. What i observed was that in the guide , they have not specified us to use any other annotations rather than `@RepositoryRestResource`. So what i have done is :

```
public class Merchant{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "account", path = "account")
public interface MerchantRepository extends MongoRepository<Merchant, String> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

and it seems to work as long as i keep everything in the same package. So, i am trying to understand why this is working even though we are not using the annotations  `@EnableMongoRepositories` etc which are normally used to provide default implementations for CRUD operations ? It is evident from the documentation that `MongoRepository` internally extends `PagingAndSortingRepository` interface ,which in turn extends `CrudRepository` interface. Can someone please explain how this is working ?

Comment: You can define separate packages and you have to @ComponentScan(your package names). @Enable* related annotations should be used in the main spring boot class.

Comment: @Sambit you are missing the point, i wanted to understand how it was working without all that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using a regular Spring (not Spring Boot) application or when not adhering to the [general recommendations for a Spring Boot application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html#using-boot-structuring-your-code) (putting the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in a [top-level package](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class)) then you must add the `@EnableMongoRepositories` annotation.

If you are using Spring Boot and follow the general recommendations you don't need to add the annotation. Spring Boot figures out by detecting Mongo and Spring Data MongoDB on the classpath you apparently want to use this. See [`MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.html) class for this (NOTE: This is a Spring Boot class NOT a Spring Data MongoDB class).

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot relies on auto-configuration. Each auto-configuration class has some triggers that enable it (like some class exists on a classpath, some bean is missing) and auto-configures some services (by registering beans etc.)

In your case you are looking for [MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.html)

> Auto-configuration for Spring Data's Mongo Repositories.
>   Activates when there is no bean of type MongoRepositoryFactoryBean configured in the context, the Spring Data Mongo MongoRepository type is on the classpath, the Mongo client driver API is on the classpath, and there is no other configured MongoRepository.
>
> Once in effect, the auto-configuration is the equivalent of enabling Mongo repositories using the EnableMongoRepositories annotation.

Comment: Why is it that this is not specified in the official doc for spring data rest with mongo ?When should we add this annotation then ?Only when the @RepositoryRestResource does not auto configure everything because of classpath or package changes ?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, I follow convention over configuration, and don't add config if spring Boot auto-configures the feature I want (this is personal opinion). I go a step further-if a trigger is simple(packaging,adding a property) I tend to modify they code to match the convention, not add custom config. If you need more control you really need to check the javadoc. There are properties read by auto config classes, you can define your own beans. If you need even more control, you can disable specific auto-comfig classes.